# Need help about SendKeys

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an app for fun but I'm having a problem. When I try to send "What a save!" to the chat, it keeps sendind SendKeys.Send("What a save") SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"). Why does it send my code instead of the sentence?

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
        const int HOTKEY2 = 2;

        string text1 = "What a save!";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
            // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
            // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 6, (int)Keys.F12);
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, HOTKEY2, 6,(int)Keys.F11);
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("QWE");
                SendKeys.Send("{Y}");
                SendKeys.Send(text1);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            }
            else if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == HOTKEY2)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("What a save!");
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually when I do CTRL + F12 it just pastes what i copied earlier, weird. Does anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You still have CTRL key pressed when you do the key combination and "What a save!" string contains the "v" letter so it acts as CTRL + V combination which pastes the last thing in your clipboard. You somehow need to simulate unrelease of CTRL key. For a workaround you can wait a second so you can release the CTRL key (physically in the given time period) before sending other keys.

```
if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //MessageBox.Show("QWE");
    SendKeys.Send("{Y}");
    SendKeys.Send(text1);
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```